# Meteor template autorun (Session variable)

Tags: meteor

Imagine I have a session variable that holds an image source. Every second, I want to the helper that contains this session to run.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.TargetTask.helpers({
    'imageSrc': function (e, template) {
      var clock = setTimeout(function() {
        var position = IMAGE_POOL.pop();
        Session.set("currentTarget", position);
      }, 1000);
      var position = Session.get("currentTarget");
      var imageSrc = '/' + position + '.bmp';
      return imageSrc;
    }
  });
```

the image sources are coming from a global `IMAGE_POOL`. However, it is possible that the pool contains two same images consecutively. In this case, `Session.set()` will be called with the same argument and the session will remain unchanged.

**Q1. When Session variable remains unchanged, does the template helper not autorun even if `Session.set()` is called?**
**Q2. If so, how should I make it run every time a new image is popped?**

Answer (score 1):

No, `Tracker` computations are not invalidated if the value doesn't change.

```
Session.set('test', false);
Tracker.autorun(function() { console.log(Session.get('test')) }); //Logs 'false'
Session.set('test', false); //Nothing
Session.set('test', true); //Logs true
```

In your case, if you want to preserve this code structure (which seems a bit heavy to me) you could instead store an object with a timestamp:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.TargetTask.helpers({
    'imageSrc': function (e, template) {

       var clock = setTimeout(function() {
         var position = IMAGE_POOL.pop();
         Session.set("currentTarget", {
           position : position,
           timestamp : Date.now()
         });
       }, 1000);

       var position = Session.get("currentTarget").position;
       var imageSrc = '/' + position + '.bmp';
       return imageSrc;
    }
  });
}
```